# JavaScript/ return an object in function

Tags: javascript

I have an object with 3 fields: num which int, str which string and arr which array. So I define it:

```
function myClass(num, str, arr) {
   this.num = num;
   this.str = str;
   this.arr =arr;
}
```

Now I have function, which it return value is myClass.  This function get string:

```
function myfunc(str){
   var str1 = str.split(" ");
   return myClass(1, str1[0], str1);
}
```

but when I run it, it returns `undefine`. How I return the `myClass` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword:

```
function myfunc(str){
   var str1 = str.split(" ");
   return new myClass(1, str1[0], str1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to `return` **`new`** `myClass(...)`

Without the `new` keyword, the `myClass` function just acts like a plain function that doesn't return anything (hence `undefined`).

*With* the `new` keyword, a new object will be created and passed as `this`, and that same object will be the default return value.

Answer (score -1):

```
function myfunc(str){
   var str1 = str.split(" ");
   return new myClass(1, str1[0], str1);//add new keyword here
}
```

The new keyword will produce an object to which the keyword **this** will refer to.